# Charge batteries in series or parallel?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion

I am using some 18650 batteries in a small project.  Since they are lithium ion batteries, I want to implement a charging system.  I have some TP4056 1A chargers for these batteries (I know 1A is slow).  My big question is: is there a difference between charging these is series or parallel?  Or am I fine either way?

Comment: You are OK unless a Lithium cell goes bad. Their fail mode by aging is to be an open circuit, blocking any attempt to charge the batteries or use them in series to get a higher voltage. There are some IC's out there designed to charge and monitor batteries in series by selecting 1 battery at a time.

Comment: Is that charger intended to charge a single cell, or several in series?  You must connect your cells in whatever configuration the charger expects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you charge them in parallel, you won't have to think about balancing them.

If you charge them in series, you'll want to monitor their individual voltages, and balance them if they start to differ.

In other words, serial charging is more of a hassle, because it requires that you either use more complex circuitry, or supervise the batteries manually.